# Can you store JavaScript and CSS files in localStorage to improve the performance of an online web app?

Tags: jquery, ios, local-storage, offline, web-applications

I'm working on a web application, which acts pretty much like a native application for both iOS and Android. However the Javascript files (jQuery + my own) and the css file together are pretty large for mobile use, which make the app slow to load if the user doesn't have 3G enabled.

I therefore started to think about storing these files offline. However aside from the cache.manifest (which in my knowledge only kicks in when there is no internet connection to enable offline use) I have found no way to this. What I ideally would like to have is to check if the files are already cached/stored and if not, use them and then store them for the next time.

Is this possible? This would reduce the time to load my app a lot as the index file itself is very small. I'm still working on slimming down the files by optimizing but this would help a lot in the meantime.

#### EDIT:

Just to provide a bit more detail, sorry if I was unclear before.

I've started building this webapp using the HTML5 boilerplate, and my .htaccess file has all JS and CSS file headers with an expiration date of 1 year.

But it seems that opening the app from the iOS Home Screen loads the .js and .css files each time, as was the case for when they are not cached. Opening the website on a desktop or even the iOS Safari web browser does seem to cache the files the right way, as changes in the Javascript and CSS are only displayed after manually refreshing the page.

It seems like opening and closing and opening the web-app from the home screen is acting as a refresh, therefore loading the files each time, even though they are stored through a cache.manifest for offline use, and the files' expiration dates are set far into the future.

#### EDIT 2:

Thought I'd include cache headers for the files. These seem to be alright.

Cache-Control max-age=31536000, public
Expires Fri, 18 May 2012 17:34:20 GMT
Vary Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding gzip Keep-Alive timeout=2, max=98

Comment: You still need to transfer the files once. Isn't it working with setting the correct cache-headers far into the future and have the server respond correctly to requests?

Comment: It seems a poor design idea to redundently keep copies of files that can be cached by the browser in storage as well- not very DRY.

Comment: If this is possible by using javascript, I could set it so this will only work for when the application is opened from the homescreen. Caching in this case doesn't seem to work, therefore the need for a solution on my end as I want to speed up the initial load for my users.

Comment: @kennebec: sure, but from what Marcus is saying, it sounds like the browser isn’t caching these files. Ideally, sure, it would, but short of getting a job at Apple/Google, Marcus can’t do much about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate this option then:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to get a browser to cache assets like javascript includes (although ultimitely these directives can be over-ridden by the user, probably not something to worry about). See [here](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) for a crash-course on caching. In particular see the HTTP header:

```
Cache-Control: public
```

which should force the browser to cache the asset. Not sure if this works across sessions, e.g if the browser is closed and re-opened, but at least only one request will be made when the user first hits your site, and won't be re-requested on subsequent page views.

Also make sure your javascript includes are minimised, and see [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) for general tips on speeding things up.

Comment: Mobile browsers can be a bit stingy about caching though, compared to desktop browsers. I think the original iPhone’s Mobile Safari wouldn’t cache any file that was over 20 KB in size when uncompressed, for example.

Comment: I'm going to read that, thank you. However I made the webapp in a way that only the index page is loaded, the rest is all done through jQuery and AJAX calls without any subsequent pages. i.e. an AJAX call, which loads user profile data and displays it. 

The problem is in that first initial load up. Over 3G and Wifi the page loads relatively quick (Still want it to be quicker but that mostly needs to done by optimizing), but without it is is slow. I also offer the app to be saved on the Homescreen, so this caching will have to work in a way like localstorage works for storing user logins.

Comment: @MarcusJoe: I don't understand. It doesn't matter how static assets are requested, if it's the same asset then it can be cached. On the other hand dynamic data _has_ to be loaded from the server. No caching strategy can help you here.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter to quickly. Sorry if it sounds confusing. I only want to cache the static js and css files. Subsequent AJAX calls are ofcourse all dynamic and can't/won't be cached. 
It is about the initial loading of the js and css files for when its loaded in both the webbrowser or Home-screen.

Comment: @MarcusJoe: well ok. Your assets have to be loaded at least ONCE, whatever the caching strategy is. Cache-control should help.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more details, I think the cache is already set correctly in my .htaccess which is almost directly from the HTML5 boilerplate.

Comment: BTW I've looked up the HTTP header for the files, seems like everything there is as it should:  
  
Cache-Control max-age=31536000, public  
Expires Fri, 18 May 2012 17:34:20 GMT  
Vary Accept-Encoding,User-Agent  
Content-Encoding gzip  Keep-Alive timeout=2, max=98

Answer (score 0):

iOS will not cache resources beyond 25k. localStorage should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been attempting to get this done without any luck. It seems the only way to do this is the follows:

- Use AppCache only for images
- Have all of your CSS and JS inline on the first page
- Once everything is loaded, have a JS script running to pull each of the scripts into localStorage
- You can version them through cookies to make sure the user has the most up-to-date copies

Have a look at http://sunpig.com/martin/archives/2011/05/21/considerations-for-caching-resources-in-localstorage.html for ideas on implementation!

I'm only halfway through but it's already working much better than depending on the appCache.

Edit: Keep in mind this is only useful for multi-page apps. If you're building a single page JS app, I don't think it's worth the effort to store back in localStorage. You might as well just inline everything and keep it there for best performance.