# Best methods for developing offline-capable mobile web applications

Tags: html, mobile-website, backbone.js, local-storage, offline

I'm curious to know your ideas on the best methodology to build **offline-capable** mobile web apps on to provide the best UX to the end user.

The end product should use localstorage and appcache but be completely transparent to the user (i.e. for cache manifest, if a user navigates away from the page before everything is downloaded, the caching is restarted).

Is the only method to provide this functionality to build it for example on Backbone.js and have a single page app where the downloads can happen asynchronously in the background?

What other frameworks / technologies have you come across?

Comment: backbone doesn't do anything special for offline applications. It's all in the manifest and localStorage.

Comment: Right but Backbone allows you the ability to place your whole site in 'one page', allowing you to perform your localstorage downloads in the background regardless of a user's actions.

Comment: backbone is an abstraction ontop of local storage. It's structure. It's just a library (a damn good library) but you don't need it. You can do it manually with teh DOM

Comment: Yup, maybe I should have reworded my question as I was mentioning backbone as an example of a tool to use to do this. Looking for best methodology to perform this (i.e. maybe a way to cache stuff in the background without having routings off a single page and hashbangs).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, offline web-apps? The two big things that I think do the trick are:

- Local storage Embedded images w/Data URI's
- (http://css-tricks.com/5970-data-uris/) Embedding
- Javascript/stylesheets in the page (no external files that are
  required for the site)

Together, those make a pretty solid offline app which is able to function without an internet connection.

Comment: I think rather then keeping all the Javascript/Stylesheets in the page, you may be better off using a manifest.

Comment: The only issue becomes when the app becomes rather large and complicated (having inline JS and CSS makes it hell to work with). I've pretty much built the app by now but still am running into offline launching issues others are having as well - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062429/can-you-store-javascript-and-css-files-in-localstorage-to-improve-the-performanc